# module not found - No module named 'woocommerce' - python

Tags: woocommerce, pip, wordpress-rest-api

when I run

```
from woocommerce import API

wcapi = API(
  url="http://domain",
  consumer_key="key",
  consumer_secret="secret",
  timeout=50
)

response = wcapi.delete('products/productID', param={'force', True})

response.json()
```

response is

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'woocommerce'
```

installing module with pip gives

```
C:\Users\info>pip install woocommerce
Requirement already satisfied: woocommerce in c:\users\info\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\info\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from woocommerce) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\info\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from requests->woocommerce) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\info\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from requests->woocommerce) (2022.9.24)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in c:\users\info\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from requests->woocommerce) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\info\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from requests->woocommerce) (1.26.12)
```

what is causing my problem?

I run code with anaconda navigator and jupyter labs

Comment: Try adding `!pip install woocommerce` above your import line, im suggesting this so that if it such that your file isnt able to use the package from where it is isntalled, then that issue will be ruled out